# Make one S3 bucket public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I have 5 S3 buckets in my account, and all of them are `Block all public access -> ON` and the same setting is also there for `Block Public Access settings for this account -> ON`.

Now I want to create a new bucket that should be `public`, and I don't want to change any of my existing buckets. So for the newly created bucket I have set `Block all public access = OFF`. But when I try to save below policy, it gives **`Access denied`** error. So I guess I have to Turn Off `Block Public Access settings for this account`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyNewImageBucketS3/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know that if I turn off account level setting, then will it affect my existing buckets?

As a second option I can configure CloudFront and serve files publicly but want to know about the public access change at the account level.

Comment: You can change the account setting without impacting existing buckets. If you are worried, double-check the settings on each bucket after you have changed the account default. For the public bucket, you want to make sure the two settings that mention 'bucket policy' are turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Block all public access = OFF; this setting is for individual s3 buckets provided you are doing it from bucket settings, so for that specific bucket you can turn this off and you are good to go.

If you want specific objects to be publicly accessible then this can be achieved via similar IAM policy you shared but to make this work turn on public access on that bucket and then you can apply IAM policy to allow specific objects and deny remaining.
Below image describes that if you change it in bucket setting, its going to effect on that specific bucket and the objects within bucket only

[image]

For more guidelines please check below AWS doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-policy-alternatives-guidelines.html